# How map a bit type in Mysql to hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets

i use the reverse engeneering in my class and get this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "bytecode", uniqueConstraints =
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean type;
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE  `bytecode`.`user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But i don't want to set 'true' or 'false' in my attribute 'type' but 1 or 0.
How can i do that in hibernate ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 9):

Hibernate has a special `numeric_boolean` type for this kind of mapping. You can configure it as follows:

```
@Type(type = "numeric_boolean")
private boolean type;
```

**See also:**

- [6.1.1. Basic value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. The following mapping in Java solved my problem:

```
@Column(name = "columnName", columnDefinition="BIT")
private Boolean columnVariable;
```

Comment: Boolean... a dangerous wrapper: defined as null if not initialized. Had lots of trouble with some poorly tested code that was throwing exception in production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to have it as a `bit` type in MySQL? The easiest solution would be to change the data type in MySQL to `tinyint(1)`.

<strike>Otherwise you should be able to map your entity type to an integer using annotations;</strike>  Not sure about this, have to look it up

```
...
@Column(nullable=false)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BooleanType")
private short type;
```

Comment: i would like to change that in the MySql, but in not the DBA so i think is better i change in hibernate then ask to change in database.
i will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28422 suggests it is a bug. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/ suggests it would be wise to skip it. But of course you can't tell the DBA to not use a bit column in MySQL - meaning either we need to use and older version of MySQL (< 5.0.3) or not use MySQL's bit + Hibernate at all.