# The same query returns nothing if boolean value in db is not 0

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to fetch a single boolean field from a huge entity. If `has_Id` in mysql db is 0, the JPA query below (simplified extract) works fine and returns the correct Boolean 'false' value. Exactly the same query does not return any result if  `has_Id` == 1.

I'm using Mysql 5.7, eclipselink as JPA implementation.

The field in question is of boolean type: 
TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

-tried with different type of Query constuctors (we use EclipseLink)

-used Long & Integer type, instead of Boolean

-the same query and parameters works fine in mysql itself.

```
try {
  TypedQuery<Boolean> query = buildQuery(Boolean.class,
  "select x.hasId from CCC x" + STD_VARS, null, new EqualFilter("tenantId", tenantId));
  return query.getSingleResult();}
catch (NoResultException e) {
   return null;
}
```

Below is the body of buildQuery:

```
protected <R> TypedQuery<R> buildQuery(Class<R> type, String select, SortInfo sortInfo, String orderTemplate, JqlFilter... filters) {
        String stm = buildStatement(select, sortInfo, orderTemplate, filters);
        EntityManager em = emProvider.get();
        TypedQuery<R> query = em.createQuery(stm, type);
        return query;
    }
```

STD_VARS are templates for `where` and `order` clauses, EqualFilter is used to fill them.

Comment: What is STD_VARS? and also buildQuery body?

Comment: @muasif80 I edited my question and presented the body of buildQuery. STD_VARS are templates for WHERE and ORDER clauses

Comment: Sorry about that but its still not clear whats going on without looking into what is STD_VARS and what does buildStatement do to all these arguments. Because in the end this stm is what you are passing to the createQuery but whats in stm finally is still not clear from the details shared by you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can share proprietary code here, but I can show debug logs of request, which are exactly the same and returns `false` when in db field in question == 0, and throws NoResultException if 1.                              
  DEBUG 2019/09/20 17:25:52.967.000 [pool-16-thread-1] org.eclipse.persistence.logging.sql   - SELECT RECORD_CALLS FROM cc_configs WHERE (TENANT_ID = ?)
 bind => [12396437-291F-4F1E-82E6-B0B1D28930AC]

Comment: OK can you change the bit(1) type to boolean if you see here this has some issues https://stackoverflow.com/a/33009493/578855

Comment: Thanx, @muasif80 I'll surely try it on Monday, but anyway I'm not sure whether this solution even if it works is applicable for us.